# C#: do enums cast themselves as strings or integers as appropriate in the context

Tags: c#, enums, casting

If I have the enum:

```
public enum VehicleType
{
    Car = 0,
    Boat = 1,
    Bike = 2,
    Spaceship = 3
}
```

and I then do:

```
int X = 10;
VehicleType vt = (VehicleType)2;
X = X + vt;
Console.WriteLine("I travel in a " + vt + " with " + X + " people.");
```

What should the output be in C#?

Comment: `Debug.Print "I travel in a " + vt + " with " + X + " people."; ` OMG! Why can't you people hire a car?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An enum's base type is int by default. It can also be a byte, sbyte, short, ushort, uint, long, or ulong if explicitly specified.

`X = X + vt` will error because it needs to be an explicit cast.

If it were `X += (int)vt;` it would be:

"I travel in a Bike with 12 people."

because when using `Console.WriteLine` all variables' ToString() methods are called so the string representation of the Enum is given (enum is 2, that equates to Bike, so Bike is returned).

Comment: My enums are evaluating to strings where it would suit. ie. I travel in a Bike with 12 people.

Comment: @Neale: the answer is incorrect. If someone is going to answer a question like this they should run the code through a compiler if they are not sure.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28VS.80%29.aspx - C# forces explicit enum casting.

Comment: You are correct that the X = X + vt will not compile because it requires an explicit cast, but you are incorrect in saying that enum casts to an int by default because enums will cast to string when concatenated to a string.

Comment: Fair enough - when ToString() is called on an Enum then a string is represented. I have implied this above by saying "Bike" is written. This is not casting! Try (string)vt - it won't work because you cannot cast an enum to a string. Learn what casting is before you start downvoting valid answers.

Comment: @Neale: your edit of the your answer makes it the best answer here, but I the answers that say that enums a represented as int are still not correct.

Comment: @Neale: I will accept this answer, only on the basis that the explicit cast is required for the x = x + vt line, not that an explicit cast is required all the time since the Console.WriteLine is compiled without such a cast.

Comment: Thanks Craig - I think you may misunderstand the concept of casting. It is a very precise term, the above is technically correct (and this is a technical forum). The arithmatic part needs an explicit cast, the other explicitally makes a call to ToString(), it is important to understand what the code is doing.

Comment: Yes, I was a bit loose with the term 'casting'. It does appear that Enums require explicit casting, however, contrary to 2 other answers, enums are not represented as ints, they are just Enums. That is why the concat function can utilise the ToString() to access the string part of the enum.

Answer (score 6):

In `X = X + vt;` vt will be casted to int.
In `"I travel in a " + vt + " with " + X + " people."` vt will be replaced to vt.ToString(), which will print the name of the enum.

Comment: [In X = X + vt; vt will be casted to int] - no it won't. There is no implicit casting method on Enums and they are sealed by the compiler so one cannot be implemented. An explicit cast is needed: X = X + (int)vt;

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28VS.80%29.aspx - C# forces explicit enum casting.

Comment: @Neale: When I try something similar in a c# compiler I am getting what this answer says so I think it is correct.  Have you tried this in a compiler?

Comment: Try compiling the exact code you have in your question - the X = X + vt; line will not compile.

Comment: If X = X + vt doesn't compile then how could vt be represented as an integer as per the other answers?

Comment: The compiler blocks the implicit conversion from the Enum to its base class (by default, int). From MSDN: "The underlying type specifies how much storage is allocated for each enumerator. However, an explicit cast is needed to convert from enum type to an integral type."

Comment: I have deselected this answer because it x = x + vt doesn't compile without an explicit cast, however I cannot accept any of the other answers because they say that enums are represented as integers which is incorrect because enums cast to string when concatenated to strings.

Comment: They do not cast to string! I've amended my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Ok, I'm not that concerned about whether the Enum is cast or whether the concat function calls toString(). One thing's for certain: the enum is not represented as an int because (2).ToString() != "Bike". Vt is never an int in the Console.Write line, it is just an Enum.

Answer (score 0):

They are represented as integers. I wish they could be represented as objects!

Comment: @Neale: the answer is incorrect. If someone is going to answer a question like this they should run the code through a compiler if they are not sure.

Comment: This is not incorrect - it is a true statement following by a valid opinion.

Comment: They are not represented as integers when they concatenated to strings, so the answer is incorrect.

Comment: I see your point, this looks more to be a misunderstanding of your question. An enum will never *cast* itself to anything other than its integral type. However, calling ToString() will return the string value.

Comment: @Oliver: it is not a correct answer. Enums when concatenated to strings are not represented as ints, so this answer is incorrect.

Comment: Agreed. ToString() is implicitly called on variables when strings are concatenated and the base type (int) is not returned, the string representation is.

Answer (score -1):

As the others already mentioned you just get an integer.

That's because the base-type of an [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) is an integer, but this can be changed to any other value type by e.g. `public enum VehicleType : ushort`.

To get some better handling with these names the [Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum_members.aspx) class has some handy functions (like [GetName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname.aspx), [IsDefined()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined.aspx) or [Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxydatf9.aspx)).

Just to answer the question *So how can you say that the enum is being represented as an int in what you have just stated?* from the comments: Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx (especially take a decent look into the last example using [Flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx)).

Comment: @Neale: the answer is incorrect. If someone is going to answer a question like this they should run the code through a compiler if they are not sure.

Comment: Then why are there 6 votes for the selected answer and no votes for any others?

Comment: That doesn't make the other answers incorrect. In fact the selected answer is the only one that is wrong (in part)!

Comment: Ok, it seems you are correct about explicit casting being required for the line: X = X + vt; However, that makes all the answers incorrect including yours, because Enums will implicitly cast to Strings.  Try it.

Comment: That's not casting. Using Console.Writeline will mean that the Enum's ToString() method is called. This does indeed return the Name as stated. None of the answers are incorrect aside from the selected one.

Comment: If ToString() is being called then is it Enum.ToString() or int.toString()? When does an enum become an int in a string concatenation?

Comment: It always has the base type of an int. That's a good reason for using enums, because they are small and efficient. The Enum type you have created will work out what the ToString() return value should be based on the int (2) and the enum type.

Comment: No - ((VehicleType)2).ToString(); = "Bike"

Comment: So how can you say that the enum is being represented as an int in what you have just stated?

Comment: I haven't said that it's represented as an int. Your question was misunderstood by everybody. A more concise version of your question should be "What does ToString() return when called on an enumeration".

Comment: You said "the selected answer is the only one that is wrong", when in fact there are several answers here that are wrong because they said that Enums are represented as ints, when they are really represented as Enums. That is why the string concat function accepts them as Objects and calls the ToString() function.

Comment: @Oliver: unless you can tell me how (2).ToString() = "Bike", there is no way that the Enum in the Console.WriteLine line is being represented as an int.  How could it?  How could the result of ToString() on an int produce "Bike"?

Comment: @Craig: you see it the wrong way. An enum has always a base value type (normally int), but that doesn't mean that a value type is automatically an enum. So what works is VehicleType vt = (VehicleType)(int)2; (The int cast is just to show you that 2 is really an integer). And it goes also the other way arount: int value = (int)VehicleType.Bike;